# Implementation of std::is_function with cv-qualifiers and ref-qualifiers

Tags: c++, type-traits

According to the [C++ reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_function), this is a valid implementation of `std::is_function` (excluding the partial specializations for variadic functions and `noexcept` specifiers for brevity):

```
template<class>
struct is_function : std::false_type { };
 
// specialization for regular functions
template<class Ret, class... Args>
struct is_function<Ret(Args...)> : std::true_type {};
 
// specialization for function types that have cv-qualifiers
template<class Ret, class... Args>
struct is_function<Ret(Args...)const> : std::true_type {};
template<class Ret, class... Args>
struct is_function<Ret(Args...)volatile> : std::true_type {};
template<class Ret, class... Args>
struct is_function<Ret(Args...)const volatile> : std::true_type {};
 
// specialization for function types that have ref-qualifiers
template<class Ret, class... Args>
struct is_function<Ret(Args...) &> : std::true_type {};
template<class Ret, class... Args>
struct is_function<Ret(Args...)const &> : std::true_type {};
template<class Ret, class... Args>
struct is_function<Ret(Args...)volatile &> : std::true_type {};
template<class Ret, class... Args>
struct is_function<Ret(Args...)const volatile &> : std::true_type {};
struct is_function<Ret(Args...) &&> : std::true_type {};
template<class Ret, class... Args>
struct is_function<Ret(Args...)const &&> : std::true_type {};
template<class Ret, class... Args>
struct is_function<Ret(Args...)volatile &&> : std::true_type {};
template<class Ret, class... Args>
struct is_function<Ret(Args...)const volatile &&> : std::true_type {};
```

However, using `std::is_function` on member functions returns `false`:

```
struct X
{
    int Test(float)
    {
        return 0;
    }
};

int main()
{
    auto x = std::is_function_v<decltype(&X::Test)>; // x is 'false'
    return 0;
}
```

As far as I understand it, cv-qualifiers and ref-qualifiers are only applicable to class member functions.

So my question is, why does the implementation of `std::is_function` specialize for all the different cv-qualifiers and ref-qualifiers when it doesn't consider member functions "functions" to begin with?

## Update:

Based on the answer below, I decided to do an experiment. I implemented my own minimal version of `std::is_function`:

```
template <class T>
struct IsFunction :
    std::integral_constant<bool, false>
{
};

template <class R, class... A>
struct IsFunction<R(A...)> :
    std::integral_constant<bool, true>
{
};

template <class T>
constexpr bool IsFunctionV = IsFunction<T>::value;
```

And then I changed the signature of `X::Test`:

```
struct X
{
    int Test(float) const
    {
        return 0;
    }
};
```

Using the `function_traits` struct provided in the answer, then I tried this:

```
auto x = IsFunctionV<function_traits<decltype(&X::Test)>::type>;
```

In this case, *x* is false. But if I add a specialization for const to my `IsFunction` as such:

```
template <class R, class... A>
struct IsFunction<R(A...) const> :
    std::integral_constant<bool, true>
{
};
```

Then x will be **true**! So the overload is important. But I'm not sure I understand why, or how `function_traits` ends up converting a "member function pointer" to a "member function", which isn't really the same as a regular function, is it...?

Comment: It is not a function by your requirements.  You only match functions with `R(*)(Args...)` but member functions are actually of type `R(C::*)(Args...)`.

Comment: See also [`std::is_member_function_pointer`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_member_function_pointer).

Comment: Yes, I realize `std::is_member_function_pointer` is available for checking member functions. Not sure what you mean by "It is not a function by your requirements" though. Calling `std::is_function_v<decltype(&X::Test)>` evaluates to `false`. This is not my requirements. This is how the standard behaves. The question is _why_ the standard implementation of `is_function` specializes for member function qualifiers when it evaluates to false for member functions anyways, regardless of qualifiers.

Comment: Where does it specialise to member function qualifiers?

Comment: Check the snippet I pasted above from a valid implementation from [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_function). There is a specialization for `const` and `volatile` function qualifiers, along with `&` and `&&` qualifiers, and all the combinations of those.

Comment: I guess that is for things like `const volatile auto & whatever = printf;`.

Comment: It's possible to directly pass a function type with cv-qualifier to `std::is_function`, as `is_function<int() const>`. These specializations are also required to make [std::is_member_function_pointer](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_member_function_pointer) and the like behave correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> As far as I understand it, cv-qualifiers and ref-qualifiers are only applicable to class member functions.

Although non-member functions cannot have cv-qualifiers or ref-qualifiers, function types can still contain them without being bound to a specific class type.

```
typedef void fc() const;
struct S { fc f; };
void S::f() const { }
```

Here, `std::is_function_v<fc>` is supposed to be `true`.

Comment: This explains a lot actually. I wasn't aware it is legal to typedef and define functions like that. I can't see a practical use case for doing something like this off the top of my head, but at least it explains why `std::is_function` is implemented like this.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a direct answer to the question but shows how you can remove the class from the member function type.

---

You can remove the class instance from the member function by a simple type trait to make the function compatible with `is_function`.  This is clearly necessary because

> Types like `std::function`, lambdas, classes with overloaded `operator()`and pointers to functions don't count as function types.
>
> <sub>http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_function</sub>

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template < typename T >
struct function_traits { typedef T type; };

template < typename T, typename C >
struct function_traits < T(C::*) > { typedef T type; };

struct X
{
    int Test(float)
    {
        return 0;
    }
};

int test(float) { return 1; }

int main()
{
    std::cout << std::boolalpha;

    auto x = std::is_function< decltype(&X::Test) >::value;
    std::cout << x << '\n';

    auto y = std::is_function< function_traits<decltype(&X::Test)>::type >::value;
    std::cout << y << '\n';

    auto z = std::is_function< function_traits<decltype(test)>::type >::value;
    std::cout << z << '\n';
}
```

[Demo on Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/lL4L7bdvIlzPy7ev)

Comment: While this is an interesting feature (I didn't know you could do this!), it doesn't quite answer the question. Again, I fully realize `std::is_function` doesn't count lambdas, functors and pointers to functions as "function types". My question is that if member functions are the only functions that can have cv/ref qualifiers, and member functions aren't "function types", then why does `std::is_function` specialize for cv/ref qualifiers?

Comment: @Zeenobit I edited my answer accordingly but will leave it here for future reference.